# Java reading only specific part in the line to put into an array

Tags: java, file-io

I'm fairly new to Java.
Have the txt file of the following

```
25/05/2022 23:55:31,180.0,45.0,13.9,Underweight
30/05/2022 22:24:05,161.0,67.0,25.8,Overweight
30/05/2022 22:58:29,121.0,98.0,66.9,Obese
30/05/2022 22:58:38,168.0,67.0,23.7,Healthy
30/05/2022 23:25:58,140.0,54.0,27.6,Overweight
```

Is there any way of reading only the part of the following data in each line into an array?

```
13.9
25.8
66.9
23.7
27.6
```

Comment: There are many ways to do it. The question is about whether the number of delimiters is fixed? If it is, you could simply use `String.lastIndexOf(",")` to get the position of the last occurring comma and use lastIndexOf again to get the position of the 2nd last comma. With the 2 indexes you obtained, simply use subsstring to get the 2nd last value. The whole thing can be done in a single line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read through each line and split the line on , (comma). Access the value you want to print using the index;

Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class SplitFileAndPrintPart {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = "TestFile.txt";

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {  //[#1]
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { // [#2]
                String[] splitLine = line.split(","); // [#3]
                System.out.println(splitLine[3]); // [#4]
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Explanation:
#1:  Reading the file using FileReader and BufferedReader; Here we are using "try with resources" so that the resources are closed automatically.
#2: Reading each line from the file and assigning it to the variable "line".
#3: Since the values are comma separated, splitting the lines using comma.
#4: Since the data you need in the 4 position (index 3), print the value at index 3.

Output:

```
13.9
25.8
66.9
23.7
27.6
```

Comment: very straight forward and easy to understand for each line of code, thank you

Answer (score -1):

First you will have to read the file using File class or some another class. You will have to read all lines and put that to List. Now these are lines and from these you can iterate and populate the final result (List) by using string.split(",") and the index you want to grab. This will be one possible way. But grabbing with index and hardcoding that might bring up issues later.

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test.txt"); 
      
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); 
      
      List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
      String string;
      List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
     
      while ((string = br.readLine()) != null) 
        lines.add(string);
      } 

     for(var line : lines){
        String[] datas = line.split(",");
        if(datas.size()>3){
            results.add(datas[3]);
         }
     }
    return lines;
```

References - [https://techblogstation.com/java/read-text-file-in-java/#:~:text=Java%20read%20file%20line%20by%20line%20using%20Files.readAllLines,Internally%20it%20uses%20BufferedReader%20to%20read%20the%20file](https://techblogstation.com/java/read-text-file-in-java/#:%7E:text=Java%20read%20file%20line%20by%20line%20using%20Files.readAllLines,Internally%20it%20uses%20BufferedReader%20to%20read%20the%20file).